# Prove that $ \lim\limits_{x\to \infty}xf(x)=0 $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits

I just need a hint not a whole solution please.

> Problem: Let 
>   $f ∈ L_1(0, ∞)$ 
>   be monotone. Prove that
>   $$ \lim\limits_{x\to \infty}xf(x)=0 $$

Comment: Isn't $f:x \mapsto x$ a trivial example?

Comment: That $f$ is not $L_1$ on the specified domain.

Comment: No. $f(x)=x \notin L_1$

Answer (score 0):

If $f\in L_1(a,\infty)$, then it follows that it is absolutely convergence.

Then $\forall \epsilon >0, \mathbb{exists~}X_0~\mathbb{such~that~for~any~2x>}X_0, by~Cauchy:~ \int_{\frac{x}{2}}^{x}f(t)dt<\epsilon$

Try finding an upper bound for the integral.

An extra hint:

> $f$ is monotonic and absolutely convergent, therefore $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=0$ and $\int_{\frac{x}{2}}^{x}f(t)dt\le xf(x)$